# Input() echo stops working after application execution. prompt is receiving data but data is not appearing in terminal window

Tags: python, command-line-interface

The title is confusing because the issue i am experiencing is confusing. My application uses a CLI interface with a standard 'while True:' infinite menu system which offers functionality as well as additional sub menus specific to the function initially chosen.

portion of my menu system so you can get the jist of it:

```
while True:
    #print the menu initially
    clear_console()
    sys.stdin.flush()
    print(menu)
    option = input("Command:")
    option = option.strip()
    if option == '1':
        while True:
            clear_console()
            print(NMlogo)
            pattern = r'\bscan\s+\d+(\s+\d+)*\b'
            nmap_scanner.networkMap('')
            sys.stdin.flush()
            option1 = input('Command:')
            option1 = option1.strip()
            
            if option1.lower() == 'refresh':
                print('reloading')
            elif option1.lower() == 'scan':
                nmap_scanner.MassPortScanner()
                print('Scan complete' +' --', now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                nmap_scanner.Report()
                option1 = input('Press Enter to exit.')
            elif re.match(pattern, option):
                scan_parameters = option.split(' ')
                scan_parameters.pop(0)
                scan_parameters = [int(x) for x in scan_parameters]
                nmap_scanner.SinglePortScan(scan_parameters)
                print('Scan complete'+' --', now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                nmap_scanner.Report()
                option1 = input('Press Enter to exit.')
            elif option1.lower() == 'back':
                break
            else:
                input(u"\u001b[33mERROR: \u001b[0m Command syntax Error. Press any key for automatic refresh.")
```

The menu option above is not the only function causing this issue but is the main perpetrator.

I have been using input() to get data from the user for menu selection, function configuration etc which is fine upon initial execution of the application. However, after running a function which can sometimes be up to 8 minutes the application is designed to loop back to the main menu. When this happens i am unable to enter any data into the application. As i'm pressing keys nothing appears within the terminal. After investigation i found that the application was receiving my input and the application ran as normal, only from that point on not user input appeared in the terminal.

I understand if that was hard to understand, English isn't my strong point but ill try summarise. After executing large portions of my application which can take 5-8 mins the application prompts input from  the user. However, visually when entering commands they do not appear in the terminal like they initially would. They are still being entered into the application it is only the visual aspect of seeing the data you are entering to the application which is the problem.

Another issue is this error is hard to replicate as sometimes the large compound functions run and loop back without issue. Does anyone under stand what could possibly be interfering with the input() function.

I've tried to clean up the code and add text to all of my input prompts but this doesnt seem to fix the issue. As i said this problem is hard to replicate thus finding the source of the issue is hard (to me).

Comment: The echoing of input back to the console doesn't happen in Python, it's handled at a lower level by the OS itself.  Hard to imagine how you could be affecting that.

Comment: I agree with you. However, it is affecting that. The functions that are executing before the input prompt utilise multiprocessing, threading, sub processes etc. Would this have an impact on then echoing of the input() function do you think?

Comment: How about clearing console after the operations?

Comment: I do currently have a function that clears the console using the following code: 'os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')'. This function clears the terminal regularly during execution.

Comment: I noticed some escape codes like `u"\u001b[33m"` are in use to color the screen. There are other codes that turn off screen echo. Could any of them be used also? BTW, you don't need `u` at the start of unicode strings in python any more. `"u001b[33m"` would do.

Comment: After some research i don't think this is the issue as well as escape codes have only been used for the colour red, Green and orange. Thank you for letting me know about  the unnecessary character ill remove them.